# Adding integer variables to a Lisp list

Tags: list, lisp, append, common-lisp

I'm creating a function that multiplies to polynomials together. Part of this involves determining whether I'm multiplying two of the same variables (5x * 3x) or two different variables (5x * 3y).

The function takes two parameters (p1 and p2) which are the polynomials to be multiplied. And they are entered in the form:

```
'(5 (x 2)) '(3 (y 3))
```

= `5x^2 * 3y^3.`

(These could be anything though..)

So i have an if statement to determine whether the variables are the same:

```
(if (EQUAL (car(car (cdr p1))) (car(car (cdr p2)))).
```

Where `(car(car (cdr p1))` and `(car(car (cdr p2))` are the `x` and `y`.

I now want to add these two variable into a list so that the list looks like `(x y)`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
(setq pList (append (car(car ( cdr p1 )))))
(setq pList (append (car(car ( cdr p2 )))))
```

But what seems to happen is the first line of code add's the `X` into the list, but the second line of code replaces the `x` with a `y`, so I'm just left with `(y)`. I've tried all sorts of things but nothing that seems to work!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun multp (p1 p2)
  (let ((x1 (caadr p1)) (x2 (caadr p2)))
    (format t "x1 is ~a, x2 is ~a~%" x1 x2)
    (let ((plist (if (equal x1 x2) (list x1) (list x1 x2))))
      (format t "plist is ~a~%" plist))))
```

then

```
(multp '(5 (x 2)) '(3 (x 3)))
=> 
x1 is X, x2 is X
plist is (X)
NIL
```

and

```
(multp '(5 (x 2)) '(3 (y 3)))
=> 
x1 is X, x2 is X
plist is (X Y)
NIL
```

Comment: How come if I try and print x1 and x2 within the function, it returns the error: Undefined Variables : X1 X2. Surely they've just been defined?

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. How would I add the (X Y) to my list 'pList'? Would I have to do it within the let statement?

Comment: I would use `let`, but it depends on what's next in your code. See my edit.

Comment: How come when I try to print pList out of the let, it returns 'pList is unbound'?

Comment: Think I've got it, thank you very much for you help!